# Turning a JSON string into an array

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know an elegant way of turning this string to array

```
{"Order_status":{"order_country":"IN","order_flat":0,"order_currncy":"INR"}}
```

need to convert the above **string to array**

```
array('Order_staus'=>array('order_country'=>'IN','order_flat'=>0,'order_currency'=>'INR'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$s = '{"Order_status":{"order_country":"IN","order_flat":0,"order_currncy":"INR"}}';
var_dump(json_decode($s, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode($JSONstr)` to convert json string to php array

and wise verse `json_encode($phparray)`  to convert to jsonstr